# R conditional mutate within function

Tags: r, ggplot2

My function plots data and how the data is ordered depends on an argument of the function. The code looks unnecessarily repetitive but I can't figure out how to make the mutate() function (or any dplyr function) depend directly on a function argument. I hoped it could handle the if/else in the mutate call itself. Any ideas?

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(item = c("a", "b", "c"),
                   mean = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4))


plot <- function(data, sort = "none"){
  
  if(sort == "desc"){
    
    data %>%
    mutate(item = fct_reorder(item, desc(mean))) %>%   
    ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = item, y = mean)) +
             geom_point()
                    
  } else if (sort == "asc") {
      
    data %>%
    mutate(item = fct_reorder(item, mean))  %>%     
    ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = item, y = mean)) +
             geom_point()
    
  } else {

    data %>%
    ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = item, y = mean)) + 
             geom_point()            
    }
}

plot(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one idea. This appears to do what you're asking for.

```
plot <- function(data, sort = "none"){
  data %>%
      mutate(item = if(sort == "asc"){ 
        fct_reorder(item, mean) } else if(sort == "desc") { 
          fct_reorder(item, desc(mean)) } else {
          item = item}) %>%   
      ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = item, y = mean)) +
      geom_point()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not statistics involved in the question, I think it belongs in the stackexchange where I see most R questions. I don't know how to port the question so I will let someone else do it.

But here is the solution - which might be less readable than yours but concise

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(item = c("a", "b", "c"),
                   mean = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4))


plot_after_sort <- function(data, sort = "none")
{
  
  data %>%
    
    {if(sort != 'none') # if sort is necessary
    {mutate(., across(item, # using across reduces repeating "item" twice with anonymous function ~ fct_reorder(., ..)
                   ~ fct_reorder(., if(sort == 'asc') mean else desc(mean)) ) )} else . # don't forget the "else ." here, defaults to NULL when if() condition is not met
    } %>% 
    
    ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = item, y = mean)) +
    geom_point()
  
}

plot_after_sort(data, 'desc')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>